# Visual Studio Architecture with Physical Components

Tags: visual-studio, architecture

Is it possible to use Visual Studio's Architecture capabilities to map code to physical components. i.e. servers, databases, files, etc.? If Visual Studio doesn't support this is there a tool that does?

In essence I'd like to be able to look at an overall code base and see where the physical boundaries are located.